# Intuition behind $Q_t=\sum \langle M^{\alpha},M^{\alpha}\rangle_t+\sum |A^{\alpha}|^3_t+|A^{\alpha}|_t+t$

Tags: probability-theory, intuition, stochastic-analysis

Consider the semimartingale $Z$, which by Doob decomposition can be written as $Z=M+A$, where M is a martingale and A is the process of total bounded variation.
I am trying to make sense of the following definition of $Q$, but I do not understand the intuition behind the author defining $Q$ in the following way. I know that something approximate would be derived considering $\langle Z,Z\rangle=\langle M+A,M+A\rangle$, by using inner product properties, in which this inner product would be the quadratic variation. But in that sense the author does not really define the terminology being employed for example || stands for quadratic variation, but why not write $\langle M^{\alpha},M^{\alpha}\rangle_t$ as $|M^{\alpha}|_t$ instead?

> Let $Z$ be the canonical decomposition of semimartingale $Z$ into a local martingale and a process of locally bounded variation. Define $$Q_t=\sum \langle M^{\alpha},M^{\alpha}\rangle_t+\sum |A^{\alpha}|^3_t+|A^{\alpha}|_t+t$$

> where $|A^{\alpha}|_t$ stands for the total variation of $A^{\alpha}$ on [0,t].Adding $t$ in the definiton makes $Q$ strictly increasing.

Then he proves the following inequality and he uses $Q$ in order to create upper bounds with respect to the martingale and bounded variation integral. I have no idea where this is coming from.

> Lemma: There is a constant $C$ depending only on $m$ and $l$ such that for any $F*$ adapted, $M(m,l)$ valued continous process $F$ and an $F*$ stopping time $\tau$:

> $$E \max_{0\leqslant t\leqslant\tau}|\int_{0}^{t}F_s dZ_s|^2\leqslant C E \int_0^{\tau}|F_s|^2dQ_s$$

In the proof the Ito isometry holds $E \left(\int_0^{\tau}|F_s|^2dQ_s\right)^2=\int_0^{\tau}|F_s|^2 dt$

I do not even know how $dt$ can be inferred from d$Q$

**Question**:

What is the intuition behind this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, what's the reference for this? What is the argument of the summation of the $\langle M^\alpha, M^\alpha\rangle_t$ in $Q$'s defintion? By the way the inequality reminds me of Burkholder-Davis-Gundy's inequality.

Comment: @user807606       Thanks for your comment! M is a martingale obtained through the doob decomposition.  You can find everything in 8 th page of https://sayanmuk.github.io/StochasticAnalysisManifolds.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in that sense the author does not really define the terminology being employed for example $|\cdot |$ stands for quadratic variation, but why not write $\langle M_\alpha, M_\alpha\rangle_t$ as $|_\alpha|_t$ instead?

The quadratic variation and the total $2$-variation are two different things. The former is a property over a partition that becomes smaller and smaller, whereas the latter takes the supremum over all partitions not relying on the partition's interval's size. That is,
$$ \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \sum_{[u,v] \in \mathcal{P}_\delta([0,1])} |X_v-X_u|^2 \neq \sup_{\mathcal{P}([0,1])} \sum_{[u,v]\in \mathcal{P}([0,1])} |X_v-X_u|^2$$
where I denoted with $\mathcal{P}_\delta$ any partition of $[0,1]$ such that each adjacent point of the partition has distance less than $\delta$ and without the $\delta$, means that it is just a partition of the given interval.

> What is the intuition behind this?

From what I gathered from the book you reference, the definition of $Q$ is pretty much defined in order for the proof of the lemma below to work.
Indeed, because it gets the integral
$$ \int_0^\tau |F_s|^2 (|A_s|^2 + 1) \; dA_s \le \frac{1}{3} \int_0^\tau |F_s|^2 d(|A_s|^3 + |A_s|)$$
and wants to collect this with respect to the same driving path of the integral part dependent on the martingale. So, instead of integrating wrt $\langle M, M \rangle$, we integrate with respect to a ''larger'' path, namely $Q$ (note that every term of $Q$ is an increasing process by definition so that the inequality $\int_0^s f(u) \, d (|A_s|^3 - |A_s|) \le \int_0^s f(u) \; dQ_s$ is trivial).

And, because the other part of the estimate is given by Ito integral over the martingale, i.e.
$$ 
\mathbb{E} \left\{ \max_{t\le \tau} \left| \int_0^t F(s)\; dM_s\right|^2 \right\} \le 4 \mathbb{E} \left\{\int_0^\tau |F(s)|^2 \; d\langle M, M\rangle_S\right\}$$
using Doob's inequality and Ito's isometry. Finally, because we defined $Q$ in such a way that ''contains'' the path generated by $\langle M, M \rangle$ we can bound it with respect to $Q$. Therefore, in the end the author collects both estimates as integrals with respect to $Q$ and obtain the claim.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It definitely helps. But I am still wondering $E \left(\int_0^{\tau}|F_s|^2dQ_s\right)^2=\int_0^{\tau}|F_s|^2 dt$. I am not seeing how the expectation of the square of dQ would be dt.

Comment: I don't see when it used in the proof. Additionally, $Q$ is not a continuous local-martingale, hence we can't really use Ito's isometry, or at best the quadratic variation is given by $\langle Q,Q\rangle_t = 0$. While, in your case we need $\langle Q, Q\rangle_t = t$.

Comment: Exactly! How do you show $\langle Q, Q\rangle_t = t$?

Comment: Assume the definition of quadratic variation as above, then $\langle Q, Q\rangle_t = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sum_{[v,u] \in \mathcal{P}_\delta} (Q_v - Q_u)^2 \le \sup_{[v,u] \in \mathcal{P}_\delta} |Q_v - Q_u| \sum_{[v,u] \in \mathcal{P}_\delta} |Q_v - Q_u|$ because the partitons are becoming smaller and smaller and smaller and $Q$ has finite variation (note that it is an increasing proces...) and it is a continuous function, the quadratic variation must go to $0$.